# My question is regarding installation of a package in VS code but im getting an error in installing it

Tags: node.js, blockchain, solidity, web3-react

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'prettier' imported from C:\Users\aryan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\86fd6f984ad48a35\node_modules\thirdweb\dist\esm\cli\commands\generate\generate.js
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:853:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:910:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1130:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:396:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:365:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:240:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

To initialize the blockchain environment, I used the command given.
->npx thirdweb@latest create --contract
I tried to install the prettier package as it is given in the error but still im getting the same error after running "npx thirdweb@latest create --contract" command.

Comment: You should create an issue on their github. Someone imported something from `prettier` [here](https://github.com/thirdweb-dev/js/blob/main/packages/thirdweb/src/cli/commands/generate/generate.ts#L21) but they never added it to the dependencies